# splitting a complex line into an array

Tags: perl

I have an array where the elements look like this (whitespaces included)

```
@array = (
"    795     0|  1",
"      5   135| 17",
"     12   161| 17",
"    244    22| 17",
"     11    25| 17",
"    249   389| 17",
"  22383   443| 17"
);
```

I need to take an element out

```
"    795     0|  1"
```

and split it into 3 numbers getting rid of the white spaces and "|" in each line.

```
@new_array =("795","0","1");
```

The problem I'm having is that the whitespace and size of the numbers varies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a regexp matching only the numbers:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper ;

my @array = (
"    795     0|  1",
"      5   135| 17",
"     12   161| 17",
"    244    22| 17",
"     11    25| 17",
"    249   389| 17",
"  22383   443| 17"
);

foreach my $item ( @array ) {
  my @tmp = $item =~ m/(\d+)/g ;
  printf "'%s' => %s\n" , $item , Dumper( \@tmp ) ;
}
```

This will also work if the string has no whitespace in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a bunch this works perfectly for what I need, the other option would work with this specific example but there's a chance that I may have an entry that doesn't have any whitespaces at the start.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
my ($empty, @array)  = split(/\|?\s+/, "    795     0|  1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something easier and readable like this could help:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (
"    795     0|  1",
"      5   135| 17",
"     12   161| 17",
"    244    22| 17",
"     11    25| 17",
"    249   389| 17",
"  22383   443| 17"
);

my $eggs;

for my $spam (@array) {
    chomp $spam;
    $spam =~ s/^\s*//;
    push @$eggs,  [ split ( /\|?\s+/, $spam ) ];
}

for my $egg (@$eggs) {
    print join (", ", @$egg);
    print "\n";
}
```

and the result is:

```
795, 0, 1
5, 135, 17
12, 161, 17
244, 22, 17
11, 25, 17
249, 389, 17
22383, 443, 17
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're spacing is truly uniform, you could use Perl's `unpack` to get at the data. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Packing-Text